# Magento 2 - re-indexing creates multiple catalogrule_product tables

Tags: magento2, database, reindex

Currently i am facing an issue with re-indexing, It creates a temporary copy of `catalogrule_product` table. I have shared an image of the tables.

[image]

And because of this the db size is growing larger. Did any one you faced the same problem. Please help !

Comment: I have the same problem, any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add this fix via composer patch or create a rewrite & add this destruct function and after that after every re-index action, all of the created temp tables must be removed :

```
     /**
     * Cleanup leftover temporary tables
     */
    public function __destruct()
    {
        foreach ($this->temporaryTables as $tableName) {
            $this->resourceConnection->getConnection()->dropTable($tableName);
        }
    }
```

this is a commit with a fix:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/e45e7e0b37b656851f9c9802913b7f799f475697

if you want to remove the old unnecessary tables (duplicates), please run this query is the database or SQL manager like PHPmyAdmin or Adminer and it should return a ready-to-paste query for removing :

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) , ';' ) 
    AS statement FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_schema = 'DATABASE_NAME' AND table_name LIKE 'catalogrule_product__temp%';
```

you'll get a result like :

```
DROP TABLE catalogrule_product__temp005e539e,catalogrule_product__temp0084349f,catalogrule_product__temp00970f8e,catalogrule_product__temp048b1806,catalogrule_product__temp05d4b2dc,catalogrule_product__temp06069961,catalogrule_product__temp06db2c4c,catalogrule_product__temp0705f4cb,catalogrule_product__temp076f7336,catalogrule_product__temp07ccc769,catalogrule_product__temp08074867,catalogrule_product__temp0918debc,catalogrule_product__temp092f9eb7,catalogrule_product__temp0a04b1d4,catalogrule_product__temp0b72c3be,catalogrule_product__temp0bf2872a,catalogrule_product__temp0d044613,catalogrule_product__temp0d95da12,catalogrule_product__temp0e036d56,catalogrule_product__temp0e254320,catalogrule_product__temp0e48a5e5,catalogrule_product__temp0e8ad833,catalogrule_product__temp0fafdfa2,catalogrule_product__temp121e144a,catalogrule_product__temp13f7346b,catalogrule_product__temp13fe2c21,catalogrule_product__temp141fc3ca,catalogrule_product__temp149bd59a,catalogrule_product__temp15dcf1e4,catalogrule_product__temp17902118;......
```

after that, just copy this and paste it like a single MySql query and check the result.